# Mostrar informacion de un Arbol binario de busqueda python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, tkinter

En una clase, tengo un método donde llamo a mi modulo de arbol binario (no le hagan caso al nombre de arbolAVL) y guardo la informacion que tomo de la base de datos:

```py
    def ingresarArbol(self):
        arbol=ArbolAVL.ArbolBinarioBusqueda()
        comando="SELECT * FROM tipo_inversion;"
        conectar=Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos()
        conectar.cursor.execute(comando)
        for dato1, self.dato2 in enumerate(conectar.cursor.fetchall()): 
            arbol.__setitem__(self.dato2[0], self.dato2)
            print(arbol.__getitem__(self.dato2[0]))
        print(arbol.__getitem__('758654'))
```

con **setitem** le paso como parametro el primer dato como clave (que es el id) y toda la demas informacion, le pongo un print para ver como va quedando cada dato:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y queda bien, además tengo otro print terminando el ciclo en donde con getitem y como parametro una de las claves, muestra los datos. 
hasta aqui todo bien, pero tengo otro método en la misma clase donde hago lo mismo, mando a llamar al arbol y con el mismo print, me muestra un 
None:

```py
    def ArbolBusqueda(self):
        arbol=ArbolAVL.ArbolBinarioBusqueda()
        if self.palabra.get() not in self.id.get():
            self.listbox.insert(0, "No existe registro con ese id")

        print(arbol.__getitem__('758654'))
```

Que no se supone que los datos ya estan en el arbol, o me equivoco, creo que no estoy entendiendo muy bien como funciona un arbol de busqueda. de cualquier manera aqui esta parte del codigo del arbol

este para agregar los datos:

```py
    def agregar(self,clave,valor):
        if self.raiz:
            self._agregar(clave,valor,self.raiz)
        else:
            self.raiz = NodoArbol(clave,valor)
        self.tamano = self.tamano + 1

    def _agregar(self,clave,valor,nodoActual):
        if clave < nodoActual.clave:
            if nodoActual.tieneHijoIzquierdo():
                self._agregar(clave,valor,nodoActual.hijoIzquierdo)
            else:
                nodoActual.hijoIzquierdo = NodoArbol(clave,valor,padre=nodoActual)
        else:
            if nodoActual.tieneHijoDerecho():
                self._agregar(clave,valor,nodoActual.hijoDerecho)
            else:
                nodoActual.hijoDerecho = NodoArbol(clave,valor,padre=nodoActual)

    def __setitem__(self,c,v): 
        self.agregar(c,v)
```

este para obtener los datos:

```py
    def obtener(self,clave):
        if self.raiz:
            res = self._obtener(clave,self.raiz)
            if res:
                return res.cargaUtil
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return None

    def _obtener(self,clave,nodoActual):
        if not nodoActual:
            return None
        elif nodoActual.clave == clave:
            return nodoActual
        elif clave < nodoActual.clave:
            return self._obtener(clave,nodoActual.hijoIzquierdo)
        else:
            return self._obtener(clave,nodoActual.hijoDerecho)

    def __getitem__(self,clave):
        return self.obtener(clave)
```

y claro, la clase nodo con sus atributos y sus funciones.
y la clase arbolbinariobusqueda()

aqui la clase completa:

```py
from tkinter import *
import psycopg2
import sys
import pprint
import Base_de_datos
import MergeSort
import ArbolAVL

class Tipo_inversion:
    def __init__(self,id=None,nombre=None,porcentaje_utilidad=None,tasa_pago=None):
            self.id=id
            self.nombre = nombre
            self.porcentaje_utilidad = porcentaje_utilidad
            self.tasa_pago =tasa_pago
    def ingresar(self):
        self.ventanaIngresar=Toplevel()
        self.ventanaIngresar.geometry("570x400")
        self.ventanaIngresar.title("Tipo de inversion")
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Tipo de inversion",font=("Cambria",14)).place(x=5,y=0)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Id: ",font=("Cambria",11)).place(x=0,y=30)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Nombre: ",font=("Cambria",11)).place(x=0,y=60)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Porcentaje de utilidad: ",font=("Cambria",11)).place(x=0,y=90)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="tasa de pago: ",font=("Cambria",11)).place(x=0,y=120)

        self.id=StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=self.id).place(x=30,y=30)
        self.nombre=StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=self.nombre).place(x=65,y=60)
        self.porcentaje_utilidad=StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=self.porcentaje_utilidad).place(x=150,y=90)
        self.tasa_pago=StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=self.tasa_pago).place(x=90,y=120)

        Button(self.ventanaIngresar,text="Guardar",font=("Cambria",11),
                width=15,command=self.BD).place(x=420,y=5)

        Button(self.ventanaIngresar,text="Modificar",font=("Cambria",11),
                width=15).place(x=420,y=365)

        Button(self.ventanaIngresar,text="Mostrar",font=("Cambria",11),
                    width=15).place(x=0,y=365)

        Button(self.ventanaIngresar,text="Ordenar",font=("Cambria",11),
                    width=15).place(x=140,y=365)

        Button(self.ventanaIngresar,text="Buscar",font=("Cambria",11),
                    width=15,command=self.Busqueda).place(x=280,y=365)

        self.ventanaIngresar.mainloop()

    def BD(self):
        conectar=Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos()
        comando="INSERT INTO tipo_inversion(id,nombre,porcentaje_utilidad,tasa_pago) VALUES('"+self.id.get()+"','"+self.nombre.get()+"','"+self.porcentaje_utilidad.get()+"','"+self.tasa_pago.get()+"')"
        print(comando)
        conectar.cursor.execute(comando)
    def Mostrar(self):
        print("hola")
    def Modificar(self):
        print("Hola")
    def Busqueda(self):
        self.ingresarArbol()
        self.palabra=None
        self.ventanaBusqueda=Toplevel()
        self.ventanaBusqueda.geometry("265x168")
        self.ventanaBusqueda.title("Buscar")
        Label(self.ventanaBusqueda, text="Ingresa el id del tipo de inversion",font=("Calibri Light",14)).place(x=5,y=0)
        self.palabra=StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaBusqueda, textvariable=self.palabra).place(x=70,y=30)
        Button(self.ventanaBusqueda,text="Buscar",font=("Cambria",11),
                width=10,command=self.ArbolBusqueda).place(x=90,y=60)
        self.listbox=Listbox(self.ventanaBusqueda, font=("Cambria",11), borderwidth=0, height=4,relief="sunken",width=30)
        self.listbox.place(x=7, y=95)

    def Buscar(self):
        comando="SELECT * FROM tipo_inversion where id='"+self.palabra.get()+"';"
        conectar=Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos()
        conectar.cursor.execute(comando)
        if self.palabra.get() not in self.id.get():
            self.listbox.insert(0, "No existe registro con ese id")
        for dato1, dato2 in enumerate(conectar.cursor.fetchall()):
            self.listbox.insert(0, "Id: {}".format(dato2[0]))
            self.listbox.insert(1, "Nombre: {}".format(dato2[1]))
            self.listbox.insert(2, "porcentaje de utilidad: {}".format(dato2[2]))
            self.listbox.insert(3, "tasa de pago: {}".format(dato2[3]))

    def ingresarArbol(self):
        self.dato2=None
        arbol=ArbolAVL.ArbolBinarioBusqueda()
        comando="SELECT * FROM tipo_inversion;"
        conectar=Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos()
        conectar.cursor.execute(comando)
        for dato1, self.dato2 in enumerate(conectar.cursor.fetchall()):
            #arbol[i]="{}".format(dato2)
            arbol.__setitem__(self.dato2[0], self.dato2)
            print(arbol.__getitem__(self.dato2[0]))
        print(arbol.__getitem__('758654'))

    def ArbolBusqueda(self):
        arbol=ArbolAVL.ArbolBinarioBusqueda()
        if self.palabra.get() not in self.id.get():
            self.listbox.insert(0, "No existe registro con ese id")

        print(arbol.__getitem__('758654'))
```

Comment: ya edite y puse la clase completa, ignora muchos puntos, hay cosas que necesito cambiar, y en base a lo que dices en el segundo comentario, también intente hacerlo de la manera objeto[indice] = valor y todo estaba bien, solo que le estuve moviendo mucho al código que lo deje así como esta ahora, pero ¿es mejor usar al objeto como un diccionario? ¿por que? en base al tercer comentario, entonces, tendría que  llamar a ese mismo arbol en la otra funcion y no crearlo con arbol=ArbolAVL.ArbolBinarioBusqueda()? o hacerlo todo en la misma funcion?

Comment: Ah y las funciones del codigo del arbol, estan en otro módulo, con class NodoArbol: y class ArbolBinarioBusqueda

Comment: @abulafia rechacé [tu sugerencia de edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/86501) porque añadías lenguaje para coloreado sintáctico cuando esta ya está definida en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/info. Además, la añadías mal (es `language: lang-python`). Finalmente, es interesante indicar que puedes usar `language-all: lang-python` para que aplique a todos los grupos, en lugar de añadir la sentencia en cada uno de ellos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin haber revisado a fondo el código, porque es complejo y hace uso de `import` para incluir clases externas cuyo código no podemos ver, sí que puedo observar algunos detalles:

La clase `ArbolAVL.ArbolBinario`, cuyo código no podemos ver completo pero por lo poco que vemos sospecho que es la misma que puede encontrarse [aqui](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythoned/Trees/ImplementacionArbolBusqueda.html), proporciona métodos como `__setitem__()` y `__getitem__()`.

Estos métodos no están pensados para ser invocados directamente como haces en tu código. Son la forma en la que podemos implementar en un tipo propio una sintaxis de acceso igual a la que Python usa para listas y diccionarios. Así, cuando python encuentra `loquesea[indice] = valor`, comprueba si el objeto `loquesea` implementa el método `__setitem__()`, y en ese caso llama a `loquesea.__setitem__(indice, valor)`. Análogamente, si `loquesea[indice]` aparece como parte de una expresión, entonces invocará a `loquesea.__getitem__(indice)` para obtener el valor.

Aunque puedes llamar directamente a esos métodos, el código queda más legible si usas la sintaxis de los corchetes. La mayor parte de métodos que tienen esta `__forma__` son para un cometido similar (podríamos decir que son para "uso interno" de python y no para que los use explícitamente el usuario). Otro ejemplo, cuando haces `x+y` y `x` es de un tipo definido por el usuario, Python intentará invocar al método `x.__add__(y)` si ese método existe. De nuevo es una cuestión de legibilidad. ¿Qué prefieres `suma = x.__add__(y)` o `suma = x+y`?

Pero lo anterior no es un error en sí mismo, es sólo *azúcar sintáctico* para ayudar a leer el programa. Lo que sí **seguramente es un error** es la forma en la que creas diferentes árboles por el código.

Cada vez que llamas a `ArbolAVL.ArbolbinarioBusqueda()` estás creando un árbol nuevo. Así por ejemplo, aquí:

```py
class Tipo_inversion:
    # ...
    def ingresarArbol(self):
        self.dato2=None 
        arbol=ArbolAVL.ArbolBinarioBusqueda()
        # ...
```

creas un árbol y lo asignas a la variable local `arbol`. Esta variable sólo existe mientras ese método se está ejecutando. Una vez el método ha terminado y retorna, la variable se destruye. El árbol al que esa variable señalaba es eliminado de memoria poco después por el recolector de basura de python (que es una parte del intérprete que se ocupa de ir liberando memoria ocupada por los datos que ya no están siendo referenciados por niguna variable).

Más adelante en otra función:

```py
class Tipo_inversion:
    # ...
    def ArbolBusqueda(self):
        arbol=ArbolAVL.ArbolBinarioBusqueda()
```

Creas un nuevo árbol (pues llamas de nuevo al constructor `ArbolAVL.ArbolBinarioBusqueda()`) y lo asignas a otra variable `arbol`, que no es la misma de antes pues la anterior ya desapareció por ser local. Este nuevo árbol está vacío, por lo que no es raro que no te imprima nada al buscar una clave. Es más, esta variable también es local y también dejará de existir una vez este método retorne.

Parece que lo que quieres por tanto es poder acceder al mismo árbol desde ambas funciones. Una técnica típica consiste en almacenar ese árbol en un atributo del objeto, en lugar de hacerlo en una variable local. Es decir, en ambas funciones cambia `arbol` por `self.arbol`.

**Detalles adicionales**. No usas las convenciones python ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) en tus nombres. Tienes métodos cuyo nombre comienza por mayúscula (como `Mostrar()`, `Modificar()`, etc.) y la mayúscula suele usarse sólo en nombres de clases. Deberían ir en minúsculas y usando `_` para separar palabras.

Veo que usas `self.` en muchas partes del código para asignar valores a cosas que no tengo claro que deban ser atributos del objeto (por ejemplo `self.listbox`, `self.dato2`, etc.) Los atributos se crean cuando son asignados por primera vez y en tu código eso ocurre en diferentes funciones por lo que es difícil ver de un vistazo cuáles son todos los atributos usados por tu clase. Es habitual inicializar todos los atributos en el constructor (aunque sea con valores vacíos o `None`) para al menos tenerlos todos juntos a la vista en un único lugar. Los atributos del objeto son como "variables" asignadas al propio objeto y se usan cuando es necesario acceder a las mismas desde diferentes métodos del objeto (como ocurrió con el `arbol` antes mencionado). No veo claro que ese sea el caso para muchos de tus usos de `self`. Revísalo y cámbialo a variables locales (quitar el `self`) si no necesitas compartirlas entre métodos. El código quedará más limpio.